# C# Bind class field to Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to bind the property `FilePath` from the class `SExcelFile` to a textblox. Here is my file structur.

[image]

Inside my `MainWindow.xaml` is just an textblox.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FilePath}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="3" Margin="5" Padding="5"/>
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public SManagerRoot ManagerRoot = new SManagerRoot();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this.ManagerRoot.ExcelFileManager.ExcelFile;
    }
}
```

`SManagerRoot.cs`

```
public class SManagerRoot
{
    #region Properties

    public SExcelFileManager ExcelFileManager = new SExcelFileManager();

    #endregion Properties
}
```

`SExcelFileManager.cs`

```
public class SExcelFileManager
{
    #region Properties

    public SExcelFile ExcelFile { get; set; }
    public SPersonManager PersonManager = new SPersonManager();

    #endregion Properties
}
```

`SExcelFile.cs`

```
public class SExcelFile : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Properties

    private string _filePath;
    public string FilePath
    {
        set { this._filePath = value; OnPropertyChanged("FilePath"); }
        get { return this._filePath; }
    }

    #endregion Properties

    #region c'tor

    public SExcelFile()
    {

    }

    public SExcelFile(string filePath)
    {
        this.FilePath = filePath;
    }

    #endregion c'tor

    #region PropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    #endregion PropertyChanged
}
```

I added a datacontext. The Binding is to the property FilePath and the `onpropertychanged` is called when the value is changed. Where is the problem?

Comment: What problems are you getting? Is nothing showing up, is the wrong thing showing up, etc.. I would suggest looking for a binding error in the debug window if one exists, as they are very helpful in "debugging" xaml binding issues

Comment: @user2455627 nothing is showing.

Comment: Look in the output window of the debugger for something like this: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: variableName' property not found on 'object' ''bindingClass' (HashCode=8910691)'. BindingExpression:Path=variableName; DataItem='bindingClass' (HashCode=8910691); target element is 'ElementType' (Name=''); target property is 'Property' (type 'Type')  P.S. I generalized all the pieces in apostrophes

Comment: you are mapped to a datacontext which never exists. `this.DataContext = this.ManagerRoot.ExcelFileManager.ExcelFile;` map it to `SExcelFile ` it will work

Comment: @AbinMathew `SExcelFile` is the type; `ExcelFile` is the property.

Comment: Is `ExcelFile` assigned a value anywhere? From what you pasted it can be `null`.

Comment: To piggy back off @SzabolcsDézsi now that I look at it, from what you have now it certainly will be null. You call the constructor on SManagerRoot, which implicitly calls the constructor on SExcelFileManager, which then does not initialize ExcelFile at all. Also it is better to initialize variables in the constructor instead of the declaration as it is clearer what is going on then

Comment: yes 'ExcelFile' is a `property` of a class which is never made initialized.  you have to initialize the class. like `ExcelFile=new ExcelFile()`

Comment: So we have an answer now...